# How can I skip the validation checks(not even entering the validation checks) in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model where geocodes are calculated before the model is saved using `geokit-rails` plugin. I have to run a Rake task where the state field is replaced by its abbreviation in the database. I was planning to use a hash with the states and its mapped abbreviations for this task. While doing this, I dont want to calculate the geocodes again, as this will take time for each record. Here is my code:

```
Site.all.each do |site|
  site.state = Site.convert_to_abbr(site.state)
  site.save(false)
end
```

`Site` model

```
US_STATES = {
  "Alabama" => "AL", 
  "Alaska" => "AK",
  ..
  ..
}

before_save :generate_lat_lon

def generate_lat_lon
  puts "Entered validation"
  @address = "#{address1}, #{city}, #{state}"
  @location = Geokit::Geocoders::MultiGeocoder.geocode(@address)

  if @location.success
    self.lat = @location.lat
    self.lon = @location.lng
  else
    self.lat = nil
    self.lon = nil
  end
end 

def self.convert_to_abbr(state_string)
  US_STATES[state_string.to_s.strip.titlecase] ? US_STATES[state_string.to_s.strip.titlecase] : state_string
end
```

But the problem with the above code is that, with `save(false)`, the validations are skipped, but the validation checkings are not skipped. So, the geocodes are calculated before saving a record and this is very time consuming. Is there a method to skip validation checking also in Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an `attr_accessor :calculate_lat_long`, and set that to `true` before anything that calls `save`.

Your model would then have:

```
before_save :generate_lat_lon, :if => :calculate_lat_lon
```

Comment: thanks..good solution..for making the default value `true`, should I use `def initialize; super; @calculate_lat_lon = true; end` and set `calculate_lat_long` to `false`, before this specific action, so that I will not have to change code in other parts.

Comment: or maybe perhaps, use `attr_accessor :dont_calculate_lat_lon` and use it like this `before_save :generate_lat_lon, :unless => :dont_calculate_lat_lon` and set it to `true` before my specific method.

Comment: I would probably use the :dont_recalculate/unless variant if recalculation was the more common case. :)

Comment: And you probably don't want to override initialize. Just drop an after_initialize method or callback in there.
More: http://blog.dalethatcher.com/2008/03/rails-dont-override-initialize-on.html

Comment: I went by the `:dont_calculate` method..aand yes, recalculation is the more common case and I agree it is a bad idea to override `initialize`..`after_initialize` seems a better option..many thanks for your help..

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
site.send(:update_without_callbacks)
```

http://ackbar.rubyforge.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#M000082